# Animate & Transform (active - rigged object)

Tags: physics, transforms

I have a simple cube with physics (an active rigged object), standing on a passive plane.On the plane there is a simple ramp (rotated plane in 45 degrees).I want to let the cube transform to the ramp so once it hits the ramp it should jump on it but it does not. I have tried to attach a bone to the cube and then transform the bone from one point to another through the ramp, but it did not work. I need your advice guys.
[image]

Comment: Maybe try this: Parent your cube to the bone. Move your bone from frame 0 (edge of the plane) to 10 (edge of the ramp). Select the cube. At frame 0, go to the Rigid Body menu, enable the Animated option and create a keyframe on this button (with "i"). At frame 9, disable the Animated option and create a new keyframe. I've tried and it works.

Comment: if it doesn't work for you please share your file

Comment: Thanks bro, Actually I have tried to do it again and it worked without even using a bone just by enabling and disabling the Animated option :). Thanks for your help

Comment: yes actually it doesn't need any bone, but as you asked with a bone, I thought you would need it

Comment: :) i was trying this so i can apply this concept on a moving car